# oops installation initialization successful - SQL Server 2019 Express Edition

Tags: sql, express, uninstallation, sql-server-2019

I am trying to install SQL server 2019 Express  Edition and I get this issue:

[image]

In logfile SSEI-Expr_20221103120025 I see this:

```
2022-11-03 12:00:36 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivityFatalException:  ExceptionMessage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. TypeName: NullReferenceException StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.Utils.GetDownloadFolder()
   at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.DetectPreviousDownloadActivity.RunActivity()
   at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.SetupEngine.ExecuteActivity(ActivityBase activity)
(07) 2022-11-03 12:00:36 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(07) 2022-11-03 12:00:36 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity:SSEIActivityEnd:Message: Finishing Activity DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity
(07) 2022-11-03 12:00:36 Activity Summaries for Scenario [BasicInstall]
(07) 2022-11-03 12:00:36 ActivityName   Outcome WasCancelled    DurationSeconds
```

It look's like SQL detect another installation and then cancel the installation.
How to remove old SQL installations?

I was expecting to get SQL Server 2019 properly installed and working as another appliaction is depend on SQL Server.

Comment: If you're trying to run the web installer interactively, I highly recommend a different approach: run the web installer, tell it to [download the media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpGKY.png), then run setup through the downloaded media rather than the web installer. If you think a previous installation is the problem and you don't want to keep it around, you can remove it from Add/Remove Programs; if that proves problematic, [there are more brute force ways](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/).

Comment: The problem described above occur on a user pc. I have downloaded the installer to C drive and run it from there. I have checked in Control Panel-Program and Features there are no installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (64-bit), so it is not possible to uninstall it. I have also checked registry, but no sign of SQL Server installation there either.

Comment: The problem described above occur on a user pc. I have downloaded the installer to C drive and run it from there. 
I have checked in Control Panel-Program and Features there are no installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (64-bit), 
so it is not possible to uninstall it. I have also checked registry, but no sign of SQL Server installation there either. 
When I search for sql server on Start, SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager does not show up.

Comment: I have earlier installed Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (64-bit) on my own pc, 
where Installation has completed successfully and SQL server 2019 works okok on my own pc for testing and it is working ok. 
Also the other application dependent on SQL Server 2019 is working ok. I think there are some traces of the SQL Server installation that is not properly and this is causing this problem with the re-installation. I have no experience using brute force ways on this tyupe of problem, but will try to check it out.

Comment: If you downloaded the media and are running setup.exe instead of the web installer, surely you get a different error message now than the one in the question (which is specific to the web installer)?

Comment: I have downloaded the media and run the setup on one of my pc and that was working ok. The next thing will be to try this on the user pc that got this error when running web installer, I will update here when this is tested.

Comment: has anyone solved it yet?